# c# PrintPageEventArgs.Graphics.DpiX unexpected value

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to print an image with highest resolution possible.

First I set printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution to highest resolution possible which is 1200x1200.

```
foreach (System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolution resolution in printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterResolutions)
            if (printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X < resolution.X)
                printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution = resolution;
```

Then I start printing.

```
printDocument1.Print();
```

But in printDocument1_PrintPage event handler when I get DPI of e.Graphics object - it equals 600!

```
void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel; 
    //e.Graphics.DpiX == 600 and e.Graphics.DpiX == 600!
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(somePicture, 0, 0, somePicture.Width, somePicture.Height);
}
```

Because of this my image becomes twice bigger and doesn't fit the page.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:**
printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterResolutions:
[image]

Comment: This kind of code only ever works in the Law & Order crime labs.  Detectives look over the shoulder of the lab technician at a fuzzy ATM image of the suspect, crusty old cop barks "Enhance!" and the face becomes clearly visible.  It is not real.  DPI for a printer is a **fixed** number.  Usually 300 for an ink-jet printer, 600 for a laser printer.  You can always tell you got a 1200 dpi printer from the empty space in your wallet.  Just stop messing with dpi, if the image is too large to fit the page then pass smaller values to DrawImage() or use Graphics.ScaleTransform.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, what does this property means (added to the question)?